# Where in the Book are the Full-Auto Rules?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e

Where in the Investigator's Handbook are the rules for full auto fire? Neither my Keeper nor I can find them anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Those rules don't appear in the Investigator Handbook. Rules for handling full auto fire are in the core rule book, on page 114, in a section called "Automatic Fire."